# Как выделить элемент ListBox другим цветом

Tags: c#, wpf

В ListBox загонятеся отсортированный массив с числами по убыванию. Как можно можно выделить первые 3 элемента другим цветом. Например, на первом месте зеленый, второй желтый, третий красный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут я вижу 3 варианта решения:

1. Переписать `ListBox`, ну или сделать для него расширения (что для меня одно и тоже).
2. В классе объекта, который выводите, сделать свойство. В Xaml проверяете это свойство при помощи триггера и задаете нужный цвет.
3. Использовать [AlternationCount](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationcount).

---

Я вам покажу пример с использованием `AlternationCount`:

```
<ListBox AlternationCount="99999">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListBoxItem/>
    <ListBoxItem/>
    <ListBoxItem/>
    <ListBoxItem/>
    <ListBoxItem/>

</ListBox>
```

Как видите тут нечего сложного нет:

- Задается `AlternationCount`. Тут смотрите сами какое число должно быть. Указанное тут число по сути означает на сколько частей вы разделяете все элементы. К примеру у вас в `ListBox` 10 элементов, вы указываете 3, значит индекс у вас будет идти как `0-1-2-0-1-2-0-1-2-0`, то есть указанные вами цвета будут повторяться. Если вы укажете число больше, чем кол-во элементов в списке, то уже будет `0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10...`, то есть каждый элемент получит свой индекс, по которому вы сможете задать нужный вам вид.
- `<Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">` - Вот тут я думаю все и так понятно. Мы первому элементу (0-й индекс) задаем цвет.

Ну и итог всего этого (первые 3 с нужным цветом, а остальные серые):

[image: Result]